# am fetching data from firebase but authData is empty when the app renders once

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to fetch data from firebase. The authData array is empty when the app renders the first time but when it renders multiple times the authData array picks some data.

```
//import firebase realtime database method
import{db} from './firebase-config';


//handling the posts from the database
const [posts, setPosts]= useState([]);

//handling the user information
const [authData, setAuthData] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
    //fetching posts from the database
    db.collection('posts').onSnapshot(snapshot => {
        setPosts(snapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
            id: doc.id, 
            post: doc.data() 
        })))
    });
                
    //fetching the users information
    db.collection('users').onSnapshot(snapshot=>{
        setAuthData(snapshot.docs.forEach((doc)=>({
            id: doc.id,
            authData: doc.data()
        })))
        console.log(authData)    
    })
},[])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the expected behavior. If you look at how you define your state:

```
const [authData, setAuthData] = useState([])
```

That `[]` in there is the initial value for the `authData` state.

Since loading data from the database takes a bit of time, the UI will initially render with the empty array you specify. Then once the data is loaded, and you call `setAuthData` it will render with the actual data.

If you don't want to render the component until the data is loaded, you could specify `null` as the default value and then detect that in your rendering code.